# Number of vertices shared by simple cycles in directed graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a digraph and assume that for all vertices $v \in V(G)$ the in-degree is the same as the out-degree. That is,
$$
d_{in}(v) = d_{out}(v)
$$
(i) Does this imply that $G$ can be split into a list of directed simple cycles $C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_k$?
(ii) Does this imply that two simple cycles (subgraphs of $G$) share at most one vertex?

If $G$ is just a simple cycle this is true, or if $G$ consists of a bunch of simple cycles stitched together at the vertices with all the edges oriented in the same direction, i.e. consider a simple cycles that branches out to another simple cycle at a vertex an so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) is true. If $G$ contains at least one edge then $G$ contains at least one cycle (just start walking from this edge through this graph until we visit some vertex a second time - since in-degree and out-degree of every vertex is the same, every vertex we visit must have at least one outgoing edge). Now we can remove this cycle and add it to our list. The remaining graph then still has the property that in- and out-degree is the same for every vertex (for every vertex contained in our cycle we removed exactly one incoming and one outgoing edge). Thus, we can continue this process until no edge of $G$ is left and our list of simple cycles contains all of $G$'s edges.

(if $G$ is connected, it actually is a cycle itself - though not necessarily a simple one. See [Eulerian Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Properties))

(ii) is false. The following graph consists of two simple cycles that share two vertices:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Nice counterexample.